# How to calculate the logarithmic maximum of n different independent simultaneous bets in Python?

Tags: python, scipy, sympy, mathematical-optimization, scipy-optimize

I am trying to calculate the logarithmic maximum of `n` different bets. However, for this example, I have 2 independent simultaneous bets.

1. Bet 1 has a win probability of 30% and decimal odds of 12.80.
2. Bet 2 also has a win probability of 30% and decimal odds of 12.80.

To calculate the logarithmic maximum of 2 independent simultaneous bets, I need to work out the probability of all 4 combinations:

1. Bet 1 Winning/Bet 2 Winning
2. Bet 1 Winning/Bet 2 Losing
3. Bet 1 Losing/Bet 2 Winning
4. Bet 1 Losing/Bet 2 Losing

Assuming `x0` is the amount between 0% and 100% of my portfolio on Bet 1 and `x1` is the amount between 0% and 100% of my portfolio on Bet 2, the mathematically optimum stakes on both bets can be solved by maximising the following expression:
`0.09log(1 + 11.8x0 + 11.8x1) + 0.21log(1 + 11.8x0 - x1) + 0.21log(1 - x0 + 11.8x1) + 0.49log(1 - x0 - x1)` which equals `x0: 0.214648, x1: 0.214648`
(The 11.8 is not a typo, it is simply 12.8 - 1, the profit).

I have tried to implement this calculation in python, with little success. Here is my current code that I need assistance with:

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize
from math import log
from itertools import product
from sympy import symbols

Bets = [[0.3, 12.8], [0.3, 12.8]]

Odds = [([i[0], 1 - i[0]]) for i in Bets]
OddsList = list(product(Odds[0], Odds[1]))
#Output [(0.3, 0.3), (0.3, 0.7), (0.7, 0.3), (0.7, 0.7)]

Probability = []
for i in range(0, len(OddsList)):
    Probability.append(OddsList[i][0] * OddsList[i][1])
#Output [0.09, 0.21, 0.21, 0.49]

Win = [([i[1] - 1, - 1]) for i in Bets]
WinList = list(product(Win[0], Win[1]))
#Output [(11.8, 11.8), (11.8, -1), (-1, 11.8), (-1, -1)]

xValues = []
for j in range(0, len(Bets)):
    xValues.append(symbols('x' + str(j)))
#Output [x0, x1]

def logarithmic_return(xValues, Probability, WinList):
    Sum = 0
    for i in range(0, len(Probability)):
        Sum += Probability[i] * log (1 + (WinList[i][0] * xValues[0]) + ((WinList[i][1] * xValues[1])))
    return Sum

minimize(logarithmic_return(xValues, Probability, WinList))
#Error TypeError: Cannot convert expression to float

# However, when I do this, it works perfectly:
logarithmic_return([0.214648, 0.214648], Probability, WinList)
#Output 0.3911621722324154
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like this is your first time mixing numerical Python with symbolic. In short, you cannot use numerical functions (like `math.log` or `scipy.optimize.minimize`) on symbolic expressions. You need to convert your symbolic expressions to lambda function first.

Let's try to fix it:

```py
from scipy.optimize import minimize
from itertools import product
from sympy import symbols, lambdify, log
import numpy as np

Bets = [[0.3, 12.8], [0.3, 12.8]]

Odds = [([i[0], 1 - i[0]]) for i in Bets]
OddsList = list(product(Odds[0], Odds[1]))
#Output [(0.3, 0.3), (0.3, 0.7), (0.7, 0.3), (0.7, 0.7)]

Probability = []
for i in range(0, len(OddsList)):
    Probability.append(OddsList[i][0] * OddsList[i][1])
#Output [0.09, 0.21, 0.21, 0.49]

Win = [([i[1] - 1, - 1]) for i in Bets]
WinList = list(product(Win[0], Win[1]))
#Output [(11.8, 11.8), (11.8, -1), (-1, 11.8), (-1, -1)]

xValues = []
for j in range(0, len(Bets)):
    xValues.append(symbols('x' + str(j)))
#Output [x0, x1]

def logarithmic_return(xValues, Probability, WinList):
    Sum = 0
    for i in range(0, len(Probability)):
        Sum += Probability[i] * log (1 + (WinList[i][0] * xValues[0]) + ((WinList[i][1] * xValues[1])))
    return Sum

# this is the symbolic expression
expr = logarithmic_return(xValues, Probability, WinList)
# convert the symbolic expression to a lambda function for
# numerical evaluation
f = lambdify(xValues, expr)
# minimize expect a function of the type f(x), not f(x0, x1).
# hence, we create a wrapper function
func_to_minimize = lambda x: f(x[0], x[1])
initial_guess = [0.5, 0.5]
minimize(func_to_minimize, initial_guess)

#      fun: -inf
# hess_inv: array([[1, 0],
#       [0, 1]])
#      jac: array([nan, nan])
#  message: 'NaN result encountered.'
#     nfev: 3
#      nit: 0
#     njev: 1
#   status: 3
#  success: False
#        x: array([0.5, 0.5])
```

As you can see, the minimization works. However it didn't find any solution. This is your problem to fix. Here, I just hint you the shape of the function you are trying to minimize.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, I am completely new to scipy/sympy. I forgot to add a negative sign in front of `Sum` to turn it from max to min. In terms of it not finding a solution, when I change the initial guess to say [0.214648, 0.214648] it works, which is unusual but is something I will have to explore. Thank you once again!

Answer (score -1):

The problem here is that `scipy.optimize.minimize` wants to be passed a function.  You are not passing a function.  You are CALLING your function, and passing its return (a float) to `minimize`.

You need:

```
minimize( logarithmic_return, xValues, args=(Probability, WinList) )
```

Comment: Thank you for your response Tim, but unfortunately it still returns 'TypeError: Cannot convert expression to float'